# Checkbox selection in table

Tags: php, html, db2

I've seen similar questions on here but the code is different when I try to implement it. I'm using php and html to connect to my db2 database, pull data from a table and display the pulled data in an html table. I'm trying to add functionality to my 'delete' button and would like to be able to mark a check-box that would highlight the selected row in the table. I'm working on my delete.php but for now I would like to implement this row selection. I found a line of code that I put at the start of my table, but how do I highlight the row? Here's what I have so far:

```
<html>
<head><title>DB Testing</title></head>




<style>
table{
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 80%;

}
td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}


</style>
<body>

<?php
//db2 express c (v10.5) in local
$database = "db";
$user = "user";
$password = "password";


//create connection
$conn = db2_connect($database, $user, $password);

//check connection
if($conn) {
    //echo "DB2 Connection succeeded.<br><br>";
    } else{
    exit("failed".db2_conn_errormsg());
    }

//select fields from database
$sql = "select 'JUNK', A, B, START_TIME, END_TIME, START_DAY,
END_DAY, C, ID, BUSINESS_AREA, ENVIRONMENT from  testtable where A='D'
and AVAILABILITY = 'Y'";
$stmt = db2_prepare($conn, $sql);

//db2_execute executes a sql statement that was prepared by db2_prepare
if($stmt){
$result = db2_execute($stmt);
if(!$result){
    echo "exec errormsg: " .db2_stmt_errormsg($stmt);
}

//the echos below output the data in an html table  
echo '<table border = 1>';
echo '<thead>';
echo '<tr>';

            echo'<th></th>';
            echo'<th>A</th>';
            echo'<th>B</th>';
            echo'<th>START_TIME</th>';
            echo'<th>END_TIME</th>';
            echo'<th>START_DAY</th>';
            echo'<th>END_DAY</th>';
            echo'<th>C</th>';
            echo'<th>ID</th>';
            echo'<th>BUSINESS_AREA</th>';
            echo'<th>ENVIRONMENT</th>';
echo '</tr>';           
echo '</thead>';
echo '<tbody>';     
while($row = db2_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {


    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td><input name=\"checkbox[]\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"".$rows['']. "\" /></td>";
    echo '<td>' . $row['A'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['B'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['START_TIME'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['END_TIME'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['START_DAY'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['END_DAY'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['C'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['ID'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['BUSINESS_AREA'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['ENVIRONMENT'] . '</td>';

    echo '</tr>';   

echo '</tbody>';

}
echo '</table>';
}else {
echo "exec errormsg: ".db2_stmt_errormsg($stmt);
}
db2_close($conn);

?>

<?php
function print_r2($val){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($val);
    echo '</pre>';
    }
    ?> 


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need some javascript to do the trick, see the snippet:

```js
function hl(ob){
  if(ob.checked == true){
   ob.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor='red';
  }
  if(ob.checked != true){
   ob.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor='white';
  }
}
```

```html
<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=5>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="1" onClick="hl(this)" /></td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="2" onClick="hl(this)" /></td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="3" onClick="hl(this)" /></td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>DB Testing</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function hl(ob){
  if(ob.checked == true){
      ob.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor='red';
  }
  if(ob.checked != true){
      ob.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor='white';
  }
}
</script>
<style>
table{
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 80%;

}
td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
//db2 express c (v10.5) in local
$database = "db";
$user = "user";
$password = "password";


//create connection
$conn = db2_connect($database, $user, $password);

//check connection
if($conn) {
    //echo "DB2 Connection succeeded.<br><br>";
    } else{
    exit("failed".db2_conn_errormsg());
    }

//select fields from database
$sql = "select 'JUNK', A, B, START_TIME, END_TIME, START_DAY,
END_DAY, C, ID, BUSINESS_AREA, ENVIRONMENT from  testtable where A='D'
and AVAILABILITY = 'Y'";
$stmt = db2_prepare($conn, $sql);

//db2_execute executes a sql statement that was prepared by db2_prepare
if($stmt){
$result = db2_execute($stmt);
if(!$result){
    echo "exec errormsg: " .db2_stmt_errormsg($stmt);
}
//the echos below output the data in an html table  
echo '<table border = 1>';
echo '<thead>';
echo '<tr>';

            echo'<th></th>';
            echo'<th>A</th>';
            echo'<th>B</th>';
            echo'<th>START_TIME</th>';
            echo'<th>END_TIME</th>';
            echo'<th>START_DAY</th>';
            echo'<th>END_DAY</th>';
            echo'<th>C</th>';
            echo'<th>ID</th>';
            echo'<th>BUSINESS_AREA</th>';
            echo'<th>ENVIRONMENT</th>';
echo '</tr>';           
echo '</thead>';
echo '<tbody>';     
while($row = db2_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {


    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td><input name=\"checkbox[]\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"".$rows['']. "\" onClick=\"hl(this)\" /></td>";
    echo '<td>' . $row['A'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['B'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['START_TIME'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['END_TIME'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['START_DAY'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['END_DAY'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['C'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['ID'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['BUSINESS_AREA'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['ENVIRONMENT'] . '</td>';

    echo '</tr>';   

echo '</tbody>';

}
echo '</table>';
}else {
echo "exec errormsg: ".db2_stmt_errormsg($stmt);
}
db2_close($conn);

?>

<?php
function print_r2($val){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($val);
    echo '</pre>';
    }
    ?> 


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @mruby, it's not a copy&paste code, it's an example. Check my answer, I've updated it. (see **EDIT**)